# How to declare variable in MethodDeclaration block

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to create a statement in `MethodDeclaration` block like this

```
SystemConfig config =new SystemConfig();
```

Below is the code I am trying but getting error "`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`" .

```
VariableDeclarationFragment newDeclFrag= ast.newVariableDeclarationFragment();
newDeclFrag.setName(ast.newSimpleName("config"));
ClassInstanceCreation systemClass = ast.newClassInstanceCreation();
critterClass.setType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName("SystemConfig")));
newDeclFrag.setInitializer(systemClass);
System.out.println("variable dec =********** "+newDeclFrag.toString());
VariableDeclarationStatement statementConfig = ast.newVariableDeclarationStatement(newDeclFrag);
block.statements().add(statementConfig);
```

Can anyone help, how to declare variable in method declaration block.

Output-

```
variable dec =********** config=new SystemConfig()
```

error

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.checkNewChild(ASTNode.java:1905)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode$NodeList.add(ASTNode.java:1269)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST.newVariableDeclarationStatement(AST.java:2420)
    at plugindemo.InitializationCodeParser.createMethodDeclaration(InitializationCodeParser.java:213)
    at plugindemo.InitializationCodeParser.add(InitializationCodeParser.java:97)
    at com.accenture.plugin.actions.CrittercismViewHandler.execute(CrittercismViewHandler.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting the exception? Which call? Is there anything else in the message?

Comment: am getting error on this line of above code   VariableDeclarationStatement statementConfig = ast.newVariableDeclarationStatement(newDeclFrag);

Comment: Okay, well that method shows three possible causes for IllegalArgumentException - does the message in the exception give any explanation?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated above question with detail error message I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to define "SystemConfig config =new SystemConfig();" is:

- define VariableDeclarationStatement with
- define a type as SimpleType
- define a name as SimpleName